# SQL error occurs while running same SQL of Access2003 in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL which is written in Access 2003. Now, I have to develop the prj with SQL Server2008 and 
occur error when running this SQL at SQL Server2008 because  First() function of Access cannot recogize in SQL Server 2008.
At SQL Server 2008, I tried with TOP() function but I still cannot slove it. Please help me.

```
  SELECT DISTINCTROW TableA.TCode,                  
  TableA.DCode,                 
  TableA.DepCode,                   
  TableA.ShouhinCode,                   
  First(TableB.TName) AS TNameFirstRecord,                  
  First(TableC.LDepName) AS LDepNameFirstRecord,                    
  First(TableD.ThingType) AS ThingTypeFirstRecord,                  
  First(TableA.GoodsName) AS GoodsNameFirstRecord,                  
  Sum(TableA.Amount) AS AmountData,                 
  Sum(TableA.MoneyAmount) AS MoneyAmountData,                   
  Sum(TableA.DetailedMoneyAmount) AS DetailedMoneyAmounData,                    
  Sum(TableA.SummaryMoneyAmount) AS SummaryMoneyAmountData,                 
  TableA.POSNo                  
 FROM (                 
 (TableA INNER JOIN TableC ON TableA.DCode = TableC.DCode)                  
 INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.TCode = TableB.TCode                   
 )                  
  INNER JOIN TableD ON TableA.DepCode = TableD.DepCode                  
 GROUP BY TableA.TCode,                 
  TableA.DCode,                 
  TableA.DepCode,                   
  TableA.ShouhinCode,                   
  TableA.POSNo                  
 ORDER BY TableA.TCode,                 
  TableA.DCode,                 
  TableA.DepCode,                   
  TableA.ShouhinCode
```

Comment: Why do you need to use distinct when you group by at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use a [Windowing Function](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/)

You replace your tables with versions that have Row Number on them

```
SELECT TableA.TCode,                  
    A.DCode,                 
    A.DepCode,                   
    A.ShouhinCode,                   
    B.TName AS TNameFirstRecord,                  
    C.LDepNamee AS LDepNameFirstRecord,                    
    D.ThingType AS ThingTypeFirstRecord,                  
    A.GoodsNameAS GoodsNameFirstRecord,                  
    Sum(A.Amount) AS AmountData,                 
    Sum(A.MoneyAmount) AS MoneyAmountData,                   
    Sum(A.DetailedMoneyAmount) AS DetailedMoneyAmounData,                    
    Sum(A.SummaryMoneyAmount) AS SummaryMoneyAmountData,                 
    A.POSNo                  
FROM 
    INNER JOIN (select row_number() over (partition by object_id ORDER BY Name DESC) as RowNumber, * from TableA) A                 
    INNER JOIN (select row_number() over (partition by object_id ORDER BY Name DESC) as RowNumber, * from TableC) C ON A.DCode = C.DCode                
    INNER JOIN (select row_number() over (partition by object_id ORDER BY Name DESC) as RowNumber, * from TableB) B ON A.TCode = B.TCode                   
    INNER JOIN (select row_number() over (partition by object_id ORDER BY Name DESC) as RowNumber, * from TableD) D ON A.DepCode = D.DepCode    

WHERE 
  A.RowNumber = 1 AND B.RowNumber = 1 AND C.RowNumber = 1 AND D.RowNumber = 1

GROUP BY A.TCode,                 
    A.DCode,                 
    A.DepCode,                   
    A.ShouhinCode,                   
    A.POSNo                  
ORDER BY A.TCode,                 
    A.DCode,                 
    A.DepCode,                   
    A.ShouhinCode
```

Comment: Excuse me, When I run with the answer that u taught me, It occurs error nera INNER JOIN statement.Can u teach me again.

Comment: please tell us what the error is - copy the whol error into the message

Comment: the error messages are: 1. Incorrect Statement Near 'Inner' Keyword, Incorrect Statement near 'C', Incorrect Statement near 'B', Incorrect Statement near 'D'

Comment: I've jsut corrected the code. Have another look. Also can you paste it into SQL Server and see which lines it complains about?

Comment: sorry I got another answer. I will try with it. Thank u so much indeed

Comment: i got the another answer and I tried with it. but, still occur following errors; it means Uncorrect statement near 'Inner' Keyword, Uncorrect Statement near 'A,B,C,D' near lines 15,16,17,18 メッセージ 156、レベル 15、状態 1、行 15
キーワード 'INNER' 付近に不適切な構文があります。
メッセージ 102、レベル 15、状態 1、行 15
'A' 付近に不適切な構文があります。
メッセージ 102、レベル 15、状態 1、行 16
'C' 付近に不適切な構文があります。
メッセージ 102、レベル 15、状態 1、行 17
'B' 付近に不適切な構文があります。
メッセージ 102、レベル 15、状態 1、行 18
'D' 付近に不適切な構文があります。